# Plink - reverse complement

Tags: bioinformatics, genetics

I am using Plink for the first time and am checking my data against some previously genotyped samples (these are the same samples so the genotypes should match up).

My data is nearly correct as in it has called homs and hets correctly but for some SNPs my data has the reverse complement.
e.g.

[image]

What command do I need in plink do I need to tell it to call the reverse complement when needed??

Answer (score 0):

I think I have got to the source of the problem should anyone else stumble across this post with the same issue.

I was using an Illumina SNP chip. Apparently there is some discrepancy in post-processing of genotype data with strand definition. These two links explain it beautifully:
[http://gengen.openbioinformatics.org/en/latest/tutorial/coding/](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/33/15/2399/3204987)
https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/33/15/2399/3204987

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).